# Encryption algorithm where proving the decryption is equal to spoiling the key?

Tags: encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, protocol-design

Is there an encryption algorithm or MAC algorithm for which **NO** zero-knowledge-proof exists, provably? I want people who want to prove that a ciphertext decrypts into some plaintext to **have** to spoil the key for decryption, or if they want to prove that message's MAC is some given MAC then they **have** to spoil the key for MAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every NP statement has a zero-knowledge proof, so there will always be a proof of decryption or MAC that doesn't reveal anything new.

But notice that doesn't prevent the *statement itself* from leaking the key!

Case in point: For the **one-time pad**, a single plaintext-ciphertext pair reveals the secret key. In a very similar way, a set of two message-tag pairs can leak the secret key in some **one-time MAC**s. Perhaps these are the primitives you are looking for?

For just slightly less primitive ciphers and MACs, preventing zero-knowledge proofs is impossible: IND-CPA security implies that even many plaintext-ciphertext pairs must not leak the encryption key. Similarly, UF-CMA security implies that many message-tag pairs must not leak the MAC key.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Thankfully, no, I am not looking for anything that is one-time. So, that weakness would not affect my particular application (this time!), but thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: If a single message-tag pair leaks the key, it's not a secure one-time MAC. *Two* message-tag pair can (and generally do) leak the key.

Comment: @Maeher Indeed, that didn't make any sense at all. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Wel.. NO. I just learned that any PSPACE problem has a ZKP.